# Is there anything to do with a dying li-ion battery when it's nearing its end of life?

Tags: laptop, power-management, battery, battery-life

Should I keep it in the fridge?
Should I constantly discharge and recharge?
Should I keep my hopes up or should I buy a new battery?

Comment: Buy a new battery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no hope for li-ion batteries in my experience, if they get old, they just get old, buy a new one, recycle the old one properly.

Li-ion batteries usually last a finite amount of time, regardless of use, though use will speed up the degradation process. Unfortunately it's just how it is. Read here for more on Li-ion batteries.

http://electronics.howstuffworks.com/everyday-tech/lithium-ion-battery.htm

Comment: Agree. When you have noticeably reduced runtime, your battery pack has lost a cell. There's no coming back from that (other than tearing the pack open and replacing the cell, a procedure not recommended for non-techies).